Put-Call parity equation, solving for the interest rate
The put-call parity equation is:
c + Ke^(-rT) = p + S_0 

I then solve for r.
Ke^(-rT) = p + S_0 - c
e^(-rT) = (p + S_0 - c)/K
ln( e^(-rT) ) = ln( (p + S_0 - c)/K )
r = (ln( (p + S_0 - c)/K ) ) / ( -T )
Recently, I got some stock and option quotes on some non-dividend paying stocks
and solved for r. I was getting a value of around 5% for r. I am thinking the expected
rate of return for the stock market is more than 5%. As such, (p - c) should be
larger. That means that either call prices are too low and/or put prices are too high. Note that T > 0 so -T will be a negative number.
Is there something I am missing? Please comment.
Note:
c is the price of the call
K is the strike price
r is the rate of interest
T is time
p is the price of the put
S_0 is the initial (current) price of the stock

What are the definitions of the terms in your parity equation?

The interest rate is the risk-free interest rate, not the expected rate of return of the stock market.
The parity equation reflects a static replication argument, not an estimate of future stock growth. Essentially the formulation you have is saying that by buying a call option and investing money risk-free so you are guaranteed to have the strike price at maturity, you'll get the same payoff as buying a put option and buying the stock right now:

If the stock is above the strike price at maturity, then with the call option you take the invested money and use it to exercise the option. With the put option you let it expire worthless. In each case you have the stock.
If the stock is below the strike price at maturity, you let the call option expire worthless and hold on to the invested money. With the put option you exercise it. In each case you have the strike price.

